# Adding a Tone to a Photograph Using Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, pantone

How cam I add a dark blue tone in Photoshop to any photograph so it looks like the two photographs I attached?

[image: Blue tone]

Comment: It doesn't work, have any suggestions?

Comment: ermmm.... **what** "doesn't work"? I failed that mind-reading class in college.

Comment: No spammy comments please, only actual answers and/or suggestions.

Comment: His suggestion is to show us what you've tried. It's a good suggestion as your question is likely to get closed for lack of effort otherwise.

Comment: Spammy comments??? I'm asking you to **show some effort** in your question. Is it too much to ask that you put *as much effort into your question as you are asking of others to put in an answer*?

Comment: If I'm ASKING how to do something, isn't it obvious I don't know how to do it? ME showing YOU isn't going to solve anything. It's a question and answer forum. If you don't have anything useful to contribute, please move on, unhelpful spammer.

Comment: ... and a little research and effort on your part is generally best. Typing your question into Google presents  tutorials. We are *not* a tutorial web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open the photo then go to Image
- After clicking Image choose Adjust color
- After that Adjust Hue/Saturation
- In the corner of the pop up click the colorize box
- Then change the hue and adjust saturation and lighting to get the blue effect that you want.

Comment: How could this work??? My version of Photoshop has no "Enhance" anywhere.

Comment: Skip the “Enhance“ part and it works like a charm.

Comment: You can also create another layer on top of your picture layer, fill it with your blue and use some mode (button next to your opacity on your layer). Some modes to use: overlay, multiply, color, hue, luminosity, etc. It might look better if your picture below that layer is in grayscale. You can play around these modes and find the effect you want by combining layers. You can also change the mode on the layer below (eg. put it to luminosity to get something close to a grayscale, and use another mode on the top layer.)